# How to get the value from the array

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

The problem this time is I always get the index of the array that I took from the function, I am still very beginner in programming so please guide me

function arr_month ():

```php
    function arr_month()
    {
        $month_names = array(
            1=>"Januari",2=>"Februari",3=>"Maret",4=>"April",5=>"Mei",6=>"Juni",
            7=>"Juli",8=>"Agustus",9=>"September",10=>"Oktober",11=>"Nopember",12=>"Desember"
        );
        return $month_names;
    }
```

here are the index on my controllers :

```php
    function index()
        {
            if($this->processData["is_view"] == false) { show_404("forbidden access ".$this->page_name, false); }
            $this->page_title_attr  .= $this->lang->line('datalist');

            $this->Tbl_asset_penyusutan_asset->defaultFieldsJoin();

            $arr_controller = array(
                "arr_fields_alias" => $this->Tbl_asset_penyusutan_asset->arr_fields_alias,
            );      

            $arr_viewElements = $this->_loadFormInput();
            $arr_permittedOperation = $this->_permittedOperation();
            $arr_controller['arr_tahun'] = $this->Tbl_asset_penyusutan_asset->tahunPerolehan();;
            $arr_controller['arr_bulan'] = arr_month();
            // $arr_tahun = $this->Tbl_asset_penyusatan_asset->tahunPerolehan()
            $arr_controller = array_merge($arr_controller ,$arr_permittedOperation);

            $this->load->view($this->page_name."_view",$arr_controller,$arr_viewElements);
        }
```

and this when i call on view :

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
     <div class="input-group">
      <label>Bulan
       <?php echo form_dropdown("bulan", $arr_bulan, set_value("bulan"), 'id="bulan" class="form-control chzn-select" data-placeholder="Pilih"  required');?>
       <?php echo form_error('bulan','<span class="label label-danger">','</span>'); ?>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
```

when I check the value using jquery, the result that comes out is not a month, but an index array of the variables that I am calling

Comment: Have you tried declaring your months as a plain array eg  `['jan', 'feb'...]` without manually setting their keys?

Answer (score 2):

```
Replace Line
$arr_controller['arr_bulan'] = arr_month();

to

$arr_controller['arr_bulan'] = array_values(arr_month());
```

Comment: it doesnt work, when i check using console.log the value still the index of array 

$("#bulan").click(function () {
  console.log($("#bulan").val());
 });

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with code. The way you retrieving the valuse from select using Jquery is the problem.

Your select is look like this

```
<select id="bulan">
   <option value="1">Jan</option>
   <option value="2">Feb</option>
   :
   :
</select>
```

This is how you can use Jquery to get values

```
//To get the value of selected item
$("#bulan").click(function () { console.log($("#bulan").val()); });

//To get the text of selected item
$("#bulan").click(function () { console.log($( "#bulan option:selected" ).text()); });
```

If you need a select like following

```
<select id="bulan">
   <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
   <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
   :
   :
</select>
```

You can do

```
$month_names = array(
        "Januari"=>"Januari","Feb"=>"Feb", .....
    );
```